# Configure Routing on RazorPages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Configure routing to enable getting images by not only the standard path by images/{image_id}

For images pages how can I configure routing like that?

```
    @page
    @model GetandTake.Pages.Categories.ImagesModel
    <h3>All Images</h3>
    @foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
    {
        @if (@category.ImagePath != null)
        {
            string imagePath = $"https://localhost:7005/" + @category.ImagePath;
            <img src="@imagePath" class="img-thumbnail" width="250px;" />
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are your images stored? What is `image_id`? Are you trying to get images from a database? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Images stored under wwwroot/uploads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo about showing images in wwwroot:

```
Configuration:
...
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
...
```

wwwroot:

[image]

view:

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
    {
        @if (@category.ImagePath != null)
        {
            <img src="/@category.ImagePath" class="img-thumbnail" width="250px;" />
           //category.ImagePath is 1.PNG here
        }
    }
```